# Associativity in Non commutative rings

Tags: ideals, noncommutative-algebra

I came across a paper, in which one of the axiom stated:
$\forall x,y \in$ R, $L$ is a left ideal of R, we have
$x(Ly)=(xL)y$
I am not able to see how this is true. Cause for the LHS we have right ideal $LR$, which is $\neq RL$.I think I am missing out on some property maybe. Any hints?

Comment: Can you give the link to this paper?

Comment: Even if $L$ is not a twosided ideal, associativity of multiplication is valid in all rings, so for any $\ell\in L$, we have $x(\ell y)=(x\ell)y$.

Comment: What’s the definition of $Ly$?

Comment: What does $LR\neq RL$ have to do with anything in your question?

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, I understood it has nothing to do with it.